# Windows 8 Pro hangs at Applying Computer Setting for 10 mins on Domain

Tags: active-directory, windows-sbs-2008, windows-8, folder-redirection, login

I have a few Windows 8 clients connected to my SBS 2008 Server. When i reboot the windows 8 machine while connected to the network it takes over 10 mins and sits at "Applying Computer Settings". If i am not connected to a network this happens very quickly. I am trying to locate if the culprit is a GPO or Software install, or something else.

I am having a problem determining what it is hanging on. 
Folder redirection is enabled and has not been a problem in the past.

Comment: Event logs?  /gpresult?  RSOP?  (In that order.)  I'd be looking specifically for a GPO that's generating 30 second network timeouts trying to grab a file from a network location that doesn't exist is is inaccessible at logon time.  Should be able to see that in Event Logs and RSOP.

Comment: You can enable Group Policy debugging by setting the GPSvcDebugLevel as described here:  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4506.group-policy-debug-log-settings.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i finally found the issue. We are connecting to a SBS server and there is a log on script for SBSlogon.exe and it is apparently not compatible with Windows 8. So i added a few lines to the sbslogon.vbs to ignore windows 8 clients and everything works great now.